# Angular/Javascript - Problem with transform Array Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, object

i would need your help, after receiving the data this way from an api call:

```
response = [
  { area: "Z", val: "work", count: 12, data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00" },
  { area: "Z", val: "not work", count: 41, data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00" },
  { area: "R", val: "work", count: 55, data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00" },
  { area: "R", val: "not work", count: 62, data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00" }
];
```

i need a method to dynamically transform this object into:

```
[
  {area:'Z',count:['03-2022':{'work':12},'04-2022':{'not work':41}]},
  {area:'R',count:['03-2022':{'work':55},'04-2022':{'not work':62}]]}
]
```

Thank you

Comment: the count array is not valid syntax. object keys must be surrounded by {}

Comment: can you shows us your most recent attempt ? your code ?

Answer (score 2):

since your `count` is not valid syntax. i assumed it is an array of objects.
These grouping problems are easily solvable using `reduce`

```js
const  response = [{ area: "Z", val: "work", count: 12, data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00" },{ area: "Z", val: "not work", count: 41, data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00" },{ area: "R", val: "work", count: 55, data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00" },{ area: "R", val: "not work", count: 62, data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00" }];

const res = Object.values(response.reduce((acc,{area,val,count,data}) => {
    if(!acc[area])acc[area]={area: area, count:[]}
  acc[area]['count'].push({[data.substring(0,7)] : {[val]:count}})
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) or [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/), here is a solution:

```js
const response = [{
    area: "Z",
    val: "work",
    count: 12,
    data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    area: "Z",
    val: "not work",
    count: 41,
    data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    area: "R",
    val: "work",
    count: 55,
    data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    area: "R",
    val: "not work",
    count: 62,
    data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00"
  }
];

const group = _.groupBy(response, 'area');

const result = _.map(_.keys(group), i => {
  return {
    area: i,
    count: _.map(group[i], j => {
      return {
        [j.data.substring(0, 7)]: {
          [j.val]: j.count
        }
      }
    })
  }
})

console.log('result', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This is a plain JS solution.

```js
const response = [{
    area: "Z",
    val: "work",
    count: 12,
    data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    area: "Z",
    val: "not work",
    count: 41,
    data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    area: "R",
    val: "work",
    count: 55,
    data: "2022-03-01T00:00:00"
  },
  {
    area: "R",
    val: "not work",
    count: 62,
    data: "2022-04-01T00:00:00"
  }
];


const groupBy = (arr, key) => {
  const initialValue = {};
  return arr.reduce((acc, cval) => {
    const myAttribute = cval[key];
    acc[myAttribute] = [...(acc[myAttribute] || []), cval]
    return acc;
  }, initialValue);
};

const group = groupBy(response, 'area');

const result = Object.keys(group).map(i => {
  return {
    area: i,
    count: group[i].map(j => {
      return {
        [j.data.substring(0, 7)]: {
          [j.val]: j.count
        }
      }
    })
  }
})

console.log(result)
```